# Get final non null fields by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
class MyObject {
  private final String name;
  private final String uuid;
}
```

how to get all fields from given objects if they are not null?
This code fails on `f.get("")` with

> cannot set final String field name...

when the field is null

```
Arrays.stream(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                .forEach(f -> {
                    try {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        system.out.println(f.getName() + ":" + f.get(""));
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Change it to                         System.out.println(f.getName() + ":" + f.get(object));

Comment: The exception message is misleading, that’s an old issue. But still, there’s no reason to assume that an empty string was a valid input to `f.get(…)` in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The first arg to `get` is supposed to be the object. So, `f.get(object)` is what you want, not `f.get("")`, which is asking for the value of the field from object `""`, which doesn't work because `""` is an instance of `java.lang.String`, not of `MyObject.class`.